# validate_presence_of parent attributes mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

User.rb model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # relationships 
  has_one :post

  #fields
  field :name, :type => String
  field :last_name, :type => String
end
```

Post.rb model

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document

  # relationships 
  belongs_to :user

  #fields
  field :title, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String

  #validations here

end
```

**Before create a post I want validate that the user have a `name` and a `last_name`. Also, I want show a error if the user has not `name` or `last_name`**

**these validations are performed on the model with callbacks or must be performed on the controller?**

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked up `validates_associated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document

  # relationships 
  belongs_to :user

  #fields
  field :title, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String

  #validations here
  validates_associated :user
  validate :must_have_name
  def must_have_name
    if !(user.present? && (user.name.present?  || user.last_name.present?))
      errors.add(:user, "add user name")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not working for me. The post object is created and the user has not `name` and `last_name`. I'm using mongoid id 3.x. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like what I had did not match what you were trying to do, so I updated my response.

Comment: Now the validation is working fine, but I can not see the errors on my view. Thank you!